# Regular Expression: getting a lazy string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing a project for my internship in a language close to javascript but I've encountered a problem with a regular expression i'm working on, the gist of it is:
I have the following text:

```
Article 1243fdsg Article hf453dfg Article ds g,f re d.4 '35 67f before here
```

I need to be able to only get the

Article ds g,f re d.4 '35 67f

part and not the whole string

I've tried a lot of things and searched online but could never find it,
my regular expression I've got so far is:

```
Article.*?before here
```

edit: the string between the last 'Article' and 'before here' can include the most used reading signs and is undetermined long so it will most of the time also include spaces and quotating marks

Comment: For the text that you have, would you expect it to get `Article 1243fdsg`and `Article hf453dfg` as well?

Comment: right now i would like to get  Article ds g,f re d.4 '35 67f  as a return

Comment: Ok - does the string actually have the text `before here`? If not, what is there at that point in the string?

Comment: as an example the string ends with 'before here' yes

Comment: Does this need to be done with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to pay attention to:

- `.` does not match newlines in JavaScript. If that is needed use `[^]` instead (or `[\S\s]`)
- Make sure `Article` does not occur (again) within the content you match. For this you can use negative look ahead: `(?!Article)`

Here is the suggested code:

```js
const text = `Article 1243fdsg Article hf453dfg Article dsgfred43567f
a line break, some spaces and 'punctuation'! before here`;

const result = text.match(/Article(((?!Article)[^])*)before here/);

console.log(result[1]);
```

If you need `Article` and `before here` to be included, then output `result[0]` instead of `result[1]`.

Note that regular expressions are not always the most efficient solution, certainly not when they need to look around. You will get better performance with other string methods, such as `split`. For example:

```js
const text = `Article 1243fdsg Article hf453dfg Article dsgfred43567f
a line break, some spaces and 'punctuation'! before here`;

const result1 = text.split("before here");
if (result1.length > 1) {
    const result = result1[0].split("Article");
    if (result.length > 1) {
        console.log(result.pop());
    }
}
```

This is more code, but guaranteed to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Look ahead positive `(?=)`

**Look Ahead:** Find expression A where expression B follows: `A(?=B)`

```
Article [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (?=before here)
```

**Output:**

```
Article dsgfred43567f
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/63BgC3/1

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem seems to go a bit deeper than i thought, the string between Article and before here can contain spaces, quotation marks and comma's

Comment: @chissie then add those in your character range `[a-zA-Z0-9,\s\?]`